# Open media player when clicked on an MP3 file

Tags: c#, media-player, media, autoplay

How to develop a media player which opens up and plays song when an MP3 file is opened. Just like in our OS when you click on MP3 file Windows media player opens up and plays song.

In my application how to handle this functionality.

Comment: Right click mp3, open with, and select your application

Comment: yeah. i know that but how to play that file in my mediaplayer coz it can not play automatically. We should supply the file to the media player when we open mp3 file. How it can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

To open your app when double clicking on a mp3: use the registry or "Right click mp3, open with, and select your application"

To play the MP3 in your app:
You will get the filepath as the first parameter of your 'main' function.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       if (args != null)
       {
         String filePath = args[0];
         SomeForm frm = new SomeForm(filePath );
       }
    }
}
```